# How to make form submission work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I press the register button, it doesn't submit. How can i make this work?

```js
< script >
  $(function() {
    //adds the 'invalid' class if textfield is empty
    $('button.btn').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventdefault();
      if ('Register User' == $(this).val()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $('.validate').length; i++) {
          if ("" == $('.validate').eq(i).val()) {
            $('.validate').eq(i).addClass('invalid');
          } else {
            $('.validate').eq(i).removeClass('invalid');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }); 
< /script>
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="validate" />
      <label class="active" for="task_name">Task Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Register User" name="createTask">Register</button>
</form>
```

I have also tried using "return false" instead of preventdefault(), still fails to submit successfully.

Comment: That's what `preventDefault` does, it prevents the default action from happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need `event.preventDefault()` (capital D).

`preventDefault` stops the action the event is about to perform, which in this case would be the form submission. That's fine, because you want to validate the input, but it means you have to then trigger the form submission yourself if you want it to go through. The simplest way to do that given your current code is to check the number of `.invalid` fields and submit if there are none, [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/66dm4xpz/):

```
$(function () {
    //adds the 'invalid' class if textfield is empty
    $('button.btn').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ('Register User' == $(this).val()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $('.validate').length; i++) {
                if ("" == $('.validate').eq(i).val()) {
                    $('.validate').eq(i).addClass('invalid');
                } else {
                    $('.validate').eq(i).removeClass('invalid');
                }
            }
            // Submit if there are no errors
            if ($('.invalid').length == 0) { 
                $('form').submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```